# Not able to factorize determinant

Tags: matrices, polynomials, determinant, factoring

I know how to solve this by determinant properties but I can't find any  intuitive way to solve this by factorization method.

$$\Delta=\left|\begin{matrix}b^2+c^2&ab&ac\\ab&c^2+a^2&bc\\ca&cb&a^2+b^2\end{matrix}\right|$$

Comment: Hint: it's a symmetric degree-$6$ polynomial that simplifies if $a=b=c$ to $4a^6$, so the highest-order term is $4a^2b^2c^2$. See how much more you can work out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $c=0$,

$$\Delta=\left|\begin{matrix}b^2&ab&0\\ab&a^2&0\\0&0&a^2+b^2\end{matrix}\right|=0$$

hence by symmetry $abc$ must be a factor. Then if you look at the terms implied in Sarrus' rule, they all include the variables squared. Hence $\lambda a^2b^2c^2$, and

$$\lambda=\left|\begin{matrix}2&1&1\\1&2&1\\1&1&2\end{matrix}\right|.$$